# How to remove "NSBundle may not respond to '-pathForResource:ofType' " warning

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, objective-c++

I am trying to expose the pathForResource functionality to C++ from objective-c.
However, I am very new to objective-c  and have not been able to discern how to use a c string as an argument in objective-c.  clearly I have the wrong idea here.
how do i get pathForResource to use c strings as an argument?

here is my function:

```
    static std::string getAssetPath(std::string name, std::string ending)
{

 const char * nameChar = name.c_str();
 const char * endingChar = ending.c_str();
 NSString* assetPath = [NSBundle pathForResource:&nameChar
            ofType:&endingChar];
 std::string str;
 str = std::string([assetPath cStringUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
 return str;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString* nameChar = [NSString stringWithCString:name.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
NSString* endingChar = [NSString stringWithCString:ending.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString* assetPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:nameChar ofType:endingChar];
```

Comment: this still leaves the warning for me though.  I could be missing something? ignore warning?

Comment: You cannot ignore that warning.  It means the method was not found; it's an error in any other language.  pathForResource:ofType is an instance method, so you need to call it on an instance of NSBundle, such as the "main bundle".  I've fixed code in my example.

Comment: wow thanks so much!  That gives me a good idea of what was going on.